# Unable to gather python interpreter info for pydev

Tags: eclipse, pydev

OS: Windows 7 x64

Python: 2.7.3

Pydev: 2.7.1.2012100913

Eclipse: Version: Juno Service Release 1  Build id: 20121004-1855

I am unable to configure a python interpreter in Pydev. If I try using the auto-configuration or the manual configuration I get the same type of error output:

> Unable to gather the needed info from the system.
>
> This usually means that your interpreter is not in the system PATH. No
>   output was in the standard output when trying to create the
>   interpreter info. The error output contains:>><<

or

> See error log for details. No output was in the standard output when
>   trying to create the interpreter info. The error output contains:>><<

Python is in my PATH. Here is the output of `interpreterInfo.py` (stdout and stderr):

```
<xml>
<version>2.7</version>
<executable>C:\Python27\python.exe</executable>
<lib path="out">D:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.7.1.2012100913\pysrc</lib>
<lib path="ins">C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg</lib>
<lib path="ins">C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\logilab_common-0.58.0-py2.7.egg</lib>
<lib path="ins">C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\logilab_astng-0.23.1-py2.7.egg</lib>
<lib path="ins">C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.1-py2.7.egg</lib>
<lib path="ins">C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pylint-0.25.1-py2.7.egg</lib>
<lib path="ins">C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rope-0.9.3-py2.7.egg</lib>
<lib path="ins">C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sphinx-1.1.3-py2.7.egg</lib>
<lib path="ins">C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docutils-0.9.1-py2.7.egg</lib>
<lib path="ins">C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.6-py2.7.egg</lib>
<lib path="ins">C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygments-1.5-py2.7.egg</lib>
<lib path="ins">C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\lxml-2.2.8-py2.7-win32.egg</lib>
<lib path="ins">C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyder-2.0.10-py2.7.egg</lib>
<lib path="out">C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip</lib>
<lib path="ins">C:\Python27\DLLs</lib>
<lib path="ins">C:\Python27\lib</lib>
<lib path="ins">C:\Python27\lib\plat-win</lib>
<lib path="ins">C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk</lib>
<lib path="ins">C:\Python27</lib>
<lib path="ins">C:\Python27\lib\site-packages</lib>
<lib path="ins">C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL</lib>
<lib path="ins">C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32</lib>
<lib path="ins">C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib</lib>
<lib path="ins">C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin</lib>
<lib path="ins">C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-ansi</lib>
<forced_lib>__builtin__</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>__main__</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_ast</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_bisect</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_codecs</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_codecs_cn</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_codecs_hk</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_codecs_iso2022</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_codecs_jp</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_codecs_kr</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_codecs_tw</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_collections</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_csv</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_functools</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_heapq</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_hotshot</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_io</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_json</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_locale</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_lsprof</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_md5</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_multibytecodec</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_random</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_sha</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_sha256</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_sha512</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_sre</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_struct</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_subprocess</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_symtable</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_warnings</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_weakref</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>_winreg</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>array</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>audioop</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>binascii</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>cPickle</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>cStringIO</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>cmath</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>datetime</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>errno</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>exceptions</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>future_builtins</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>gc</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>imageop</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>imp</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>itertools</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>marshal</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>math</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>mmap</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>msvcrt</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>nt</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>operator</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>parser</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>signal</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>strop</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>sys</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>thread</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>time</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>xxsubtype</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>zipimport</forced_lib>
<forced_lib>zlib</forced_lib>
</xml>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.7.1.2012100913\pysrc\interpreterInfo.py", line 199, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError('Ok, this is so that it shows the output (ugly hack for some platforms, so that it releases the output).')
RuntimeError: Ok, this is so that it shows the output (ugly hack for some platforms, so that it releases the output).
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I did not expect such a  problem: (PyDev worked on 27 64-bit PCs under Indigo; I tested The Same PyDev plus Python under Juno on a 32-bit Pc with success; Then by the first attempt on a 64-bit PC came the error ...
I have not used  "autoconfig" at all. I was going the line 
"File>New>PyDevProject> ...PrjectName... click_here_to_configure_an_interpreter_not_listed" when it happened."

After short googleing the luck came:-)

http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html
                                              helped me to solve the problem ,
using just an alternative path to the same thing.
{1. Go to: window > preferences > PyDev > Interpreter - (Python/Jython/IronPython). ...}

Comment: I am not sure if I am understanding you correctly, but I think I already tried that. I have tried giving the path to the python interpreter myself instead of auto-configuration, and I still get the error listed above. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I could not manually or automatically configure. I worked around the problem by re-installing python 2.7. After re-install auto-configuration worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Python 3, so I had to make these
changes to get python.exe as my interpreter.
File:

> C:\EasyEclipse-for-LAMP-1.2.2.2\extensions
>   \pydev-1.3.3\eclipse\plugins \org.python.pydev_1.3.3\PySrc
>   \interpreterInfo.py

Edit all occurrences of “`print …`” to “

```
print(…)
```

” (the … is whatever is being printed), so wrap it in quotes.

Comment out line 16, since `True` and `False` are
considered keywords in Python 3.
Save, and you should be able to successfully
set `C:\Python32\python.exe` as the interpreter.
I kept the default folders checked.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem on Windows after directly copying my python 2.7 (64bits) directory to a new computer. Neither automatic not manual configuration would work, and I had the same errors as you did.

I came back to the original installation, went to C:\Windows\System32 (you might also check SysWOW64, but I'm not sure Python even uses it) and fetched :

- python27.dll
- pythoncom27.dll
- pythoncomloader27.dll
- pywintypes27.dll

I copied them into the new computer's System32 and pydev's autoconfig was able to find my python interpreter from the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Please Make sure you have installed proper version [32 or 64 bit] of python corresponding to your system OS version

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. Try to run "python --version" to see that python executes in your system

Answer (score 0):

1. Install OS compatible python executable in your machine.
   During installation remember to check "Add Python 3.8 to PATH. (as shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v65GI.png))
2. Once Python installed successfully in your machine In Eclipse open in the Window -> Preference -> Pydev -> Interpreter -> Python Interpreters menu. (Assuming you already installed PyDev plugin in Eclipse).
3. Next select Config first in PATH option. (as shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOheV.png))

You can now see the Python interpreter info in eclipse. (as shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6vQZ.png))