# Error when declaring python interpreter in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm attempting to use python in eclipse and am having trouble with the python interpreter. I am using Eclipse 2018-09 and the latest PyDev and Python 3.7.1. When declaring python-3.7.1.exe as an interpreter it gives an error saying it was unable to get info on the interpreter. It also says a possibility to why could be using an unsupported version. I don't know where to go from here, another piece of information is that I am doing this on a school computer with teacher permission but I don't know if that could be causing an issue or not? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039194/unable-to-gather-python-interpreter-info-for-pydev) will help? Please paste any errors that you're getting.

Comment: I took a screenshot of the error; https://pasteboard.co/HNVRgK8.png (The error message says: 'No output was in the standard output when trying to create the interpreter info for: C:\Users\601247002\python-3.7.1.exe The error output contains:>><<